# Can someone help me to get buffered reader to work in Java?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Here I am trying to read a document that has words and corresponding abbreviations. E.g.

```
one,1
two,2
easy,ez
```

Each line is separated, and the words are separated from the abbreviations with a comma.

---

When I want the buffered reader to keep reading lines using

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
```

it won't. It will only read the first line. This means it will display the abbreviation for one, which is 1. But if I input another value say two, I get this error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at shortener.NewClass.Short(NewClass.java:41)
    at shortener.NewClass.main(NewClass.java:26)
Java Result:
```

---

here's the code

```
public static String Short(String input) {

    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("abbreviations.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            for(int i = 0; i <= line.length(); i++) {
                if(line.charAt(i) == ','){
                    String strOrig = line.substring(0, i);
                    if(strOrig.equals(input)) {
                        String strAbv = line.substring(line.length()-1);
                        return strAbv;
                        }
                    }                
                }
            }   
        br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        out.println("File Not found");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made the conditional expression in `for` loop as *i lesser than or equal to line.length()*. That's wrong.`i` shouldn't be equal to the length of the line. Change this

```
for(int i = 0; i <= line.length(); i++)
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
```

you can't make `i` equal to the length of line. The index starts from `0`. so, the valid indexes would be from `0` to `length-1`

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= line.length(); i++) {
```

as it is accessing one too many. To correct:

```
for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
```

Note that the posted code does not `close()` the reader if the abbreviation is found. Use a [`finally`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) block or [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement to ensue the reader is closed.

Other:

- [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) could be used to separate the line into two tokens instead of explicitly coding the separation.
- A [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) style file could be used to store the *abbreviation-to-term* map instead of a comma separated file. The `Properties` class provides a mechanism for loading the file and methods for searching the map:

  ```
     // If the 'abbreviations.txt' file is not updated
     // by the program then arrange for it to be loaded once.
     //
     try (final FileInputStream is =
              new FileInputStream("abbreviations.txt"))
     {
         final Properties p = new Properties();
         p.load(is);
         return p.getProperty(input);
     }
  ```

Comment: +1 for suggesting the use of `.split()`. Possibly give an example of how this could be better done using it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `for` loop part of your code:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= line.length(); i++) {
```

It should be changed to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
```

Notice how `<=` was changed to `<`:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= line.length(); i++) {
//vs:
for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
```

For pretty much all coding, including `java`, counting starts at 0. So where you would normally say 5, in coding you would say 4.

Let's say the length of the array is `3`, meaning it contains `0`, `1`, and `2`. So, when doing this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= line.length(); i++) {
//length of the line is 3, so:
for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
```

now, it will loop threw the numbers `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`. Yet, the line is only contains only `0`, `1`, and `2`. So, if we were to do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
//length of the line is 3, so:
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
```

Using this new code, it will loop threw `0`, `1`, and `2`, the same length of our line, `0`, `1`, and `2`.