# How do I use BufferedReader to read lines from a txt file into an array

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I know how to read in lines with `Scanner`, but how do I use a `BufferedReader`? I want to be able to read lines into an array. I am able to use the `hasNext()` function with a `Scanner` but not a `BufferedReader`, that is the only thing I don't know how to do. How do I check when the end of the file text has been reached?

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("weblog.txt"));

String[] fileRead = new String[2990];
int count = 0;

while (fileRead[count] != null) {
    fileRead[count] = reader.readLine();
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Could you add the relevant tags to the post? (Java, for example) :)

Comment: Hint :  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/bufferedreader_readline.htm

Comment: Here is a post on that:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22840689/can-someone-help-me-to-get-buffered-reader-to-work-in-java

Comment: If you like to stay in the programmer business, then you should start to learn to do research on your own. There a hundrets of examples and tutorials about reading files with a `BufferedReader` and you haven't found one of them?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) that `readLine()` returns `null` if the end of the stream is reached.

The usual idiom is to update the variable that holds the current line in the while condition and check if it's not null:

```
String currentLine;
while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   //do something with line
}
```

As an aside, you might not know in advance the number of lines you will read, so I suggest you use a list instead of an array.

If you plan to read all the file's content, you can use `Files.readAllLines` instead:

```
//or whatever the file is encoded with
List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("weblog.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Answer (score 1):

`readLine()` returns `null` **after** reaching `EOF`.

Just

```
do {
  fileRead[count] = reader.readLine();
  count++;
} while (fileRead[count-1]) != null);
```

Of course this piece of code is not the recommended way of reading the file, but shows how it might be done if you want to do it exactly the way you attempted to ( some predefined size array, counter etc. )

Comment: The correct way would be to use some kind of list correct? I'm just getting into i/o and haven't any concrete way of learning the rite methods on text/binary io. For this example I just wanted to see this particular way of storing was possible. Thanks!

Comment: @HugoPerea Yeah, lists are very flexible and are perfect for storing unknown amount of objects. They'd also reduce need of counter, as you can check number of objects in the list with its `size()` method.

Comment: @HugoPerea *"The correct way would be to use some kind of list correct?"* And to avoid adding stuff to your collection that is not part of the read text file, like this code currently does.

Comment: Whats the best kind of combination to read a a large text file? My teacher uses a scanner and FileInputStream.

Answer (score 1):

using `readLine()`, [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html) and [`Vector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

```
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\weblog.txt")))
    {
        String line;
        Vector<String> fileRead = new Vector<String>();

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            fileRead.add(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
```